# Visual Studio LoadTest appears to record incorrect times

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

Have just started using Visual Studio to load test a web application. I have set up a number of load tests successfully but I am having an issue with one particular test. It happens to be the first time I am including a File Upload, so possibly that has something to do with it.

The LoadTest includes one WebTest that performs the File Upload. After completion the Test Details table shows most of the WebTest's taking ~100-120 seconds to complete. When drilling into the Test Log for each WebTest execution and adding up the Request Time components the result is the expected ~1-3 seconds.

Running the WebTest by itself also gets the expected ~1-3 seconds.

Think times are turned off.

I expect there is a parameter/config value that I have overlooked. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could shed any light on this.

Comment: I cannot think of anything relevant to suggest. You need to add a lot more details of the problem test to get any real help. Can you [edit] the question to provide a [mcve]? If not then this question is likely to be closed as "too broad". See the [help] pages for how to write a good question that is on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. In the properties for the load test scenario there is a "Think Profile" option. It was set to "Normal Distribution". For what I am trying to achieve it needed to set it to "Off".

Comment: This question already states that *"Think times are turned off."*